# How can I get asp.net MVC to fall back to property injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

Say my view has a hidden input.  Now I want this hidden to be populated into a public property of my controller base on any request that includes it.

Can I do this?

The end result would be a property on my base controller that was populated for any request containing a matching named item.

```
public class ControllerBase
{
   public bool Debug{ get; set; }
}

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
   public ActionResult Action1()
   {
      return View(base.Debug ? "in debug mode" : "not in debug mode");
   }
}
```

Another thing that seems possible would be the same idea using constructor injection.

Basically I think I'm saying, can there be a step where the available data in the request tweaks the DI container to set you up with some of that information before the controller gets called?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a relatively simple way is to create an ActionFilter and apply it to ControllerBase. Let's say you made it DebugModeAttribute.

```
public class DebugModeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["hidden_var"] == "true")
        {
            var controller = filterContext.Controller as ControllerBase;
            if (controller != null)
                controller.Debug = true;
        }
    }
}
```

It should get the job done, although it might not be the cleanest looking solution. Regardless of the solution though, you'll have to be careful if your DI container isn't creating new instances for each request. Might be safer to modify the HttpContext.Items and add a getter on the base that will read out the value stored there.